# How to establish binary interoperability between rust and c/c++?

Tags: c, rust, networking

I'm developing a simple binary protocol for a networked client/server system. The server is c/c++, and one of the clients I wanted to start with was rust.

bincode looks like a good fit but it looks like I'd have to have two structures, one with the helpful types and one with the POD types to define the networking format, or am I missing something?

```
enum DeviceTypes {
    A,
    B,
    C
}

// with the types in place
// but bincode would encode 't' as u32 per 'Bincode will encode enum variants as a u32'
struct WorkingDevStruct {
    t: DeviceTypes
}

// to ensure bincode sizes 't' to 16bits
struct NetworkDevStruct {
    t: u16
}
```

Comment: Check out CXX: https://cxx.rs/

Comment: Are you asking for us to recommend a serialization format that can work with both C++ or Rust? Or how to have C++ access Rust structures or vice versa? Bincode is the former.

Comment: If you add `#[repr(u16)]` before your `enum` declaration, it should encode `t` as `u16`.

Comment: @Jmb I don't think so, at least for `#[repr(u8)]` that's [documented to be false](https://github.com/bincode-org/bincode#why-does-bincode-not-respect-repru8). And [it doesn't respect `#[repr(u16)]` either for my short test](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#LyoKW2RlcGVuZGVuY2llc10KYmluY29kZSA9ICIqIgpzZXJkZSA9IHsgdmVyc2lvbiA9ICIqIiwgZmVhdHVyZXMgPSBbImRlcml2ZSJdIH0KKi8KCmZuIG1haW4oKSB7CiAgICAjW2Rlcml2ZShzZXJkZTo6U2VyaWFsaXplKV0KICAgICNbcmVwcih1MTYpXQogICAgZW51bSBGb28gewogICAgICAgIEEsCiAgICAgICAgQiwKICAgIH0KICAgIGRiZyEoYmluY29kZTo6c2VyaWFsaXplKCZGb286OkEpKTsKfQ==)

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo correct, a network serialization protocol that can work with c++ and rust (and python, and javascript later but rust is first client).

Comment: @cafce25 good point. OTOH, [`bincode` defaults to `varint` encoding](https://docs.rs/bincode/latest/bincode/config/trait.Options.html#options), so the int size used by the program doesn't matter to the wire protocol (and the other language can use another size and still be interoperable as long as the value can be represented in the used type).